# Regexp: negative lookahead that don't allow an open tag inside a tag

Tags: regex, regex-look-ahead

I'm looking for a negative lookahead that don't allow an open tag inside a tag, I try

### failing negative lookahead #1

```
/(<(\w+)[^>]*>)((?!<\2).*?)(<\/\2>)/gs
```

[see the example](https://regex101.com/r/rSs30j/1)

### failing negative lookahead #2

```
/(<(\w+)[^>]*>)((?!<\2).*)(<\/\2>)/gs
```

[see the example](https://regex101.com/r/rSs30j/2)

```xml
alpha
<div>
alpha<div>
beta<div>
x < y divided by 4
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div>
    <span style="font-size: 8pt;" disabled title="data">
        <span>
          infinite
        </span>
        <?= $record->id ?>
    </span>
    <div> equal </div>
</div>


<div> sum </div>

When x y and y > 0 
<div  style="font-size: 8pt;" >Summary</div> 
Equation id <?= $equation->id ?>
```

In this exampled they're the once containing:

- x < y divided by 4
- infinite
- equal
- sum
- summary

Comment: Does this solve your problem? Check the [substitution part](https://regex101.com/r/lf74GS/1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a regex you may want to use:

[`.*?<(\w+)[^>]*>((?:(?!<\1>).)*?)<\/\1>|.*`](https://regex101.com/r/lf74GS/1)

Click on it for explanation and also to see how to use it.